# Android emulator crash logs

Tags: android, crash, emulation, jenkins

I'm using jenkins with the android plugin but it seems that my emulator dies during the build. The logcat goes to the point when some activity is started but then nothing any more. So it clearly did not shut down properly. Is there some other log that I can enable to debug this issue? Might be caused by the emulator going out of memory.

Comment: Are there no clues in the Console Output in Jenkins? If the emulator crashes, normally it's reported there. Which OS are you on?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can start the Emulator with the `-verbose` or `-logcat` option. Have a look in the `Debug` section of the android emulator command line parameters.

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#common

Comment: Dead link. Can you provide the steps needed?

Comment: `emulator -list-avds` to get a virtual device name, then `emulator @name -verbose` or for even more logs `emulator @name -logcat '*:v'`

Comment: These logs don't capture details of the emulator crash