# Android emulator unable to launch on iMac in the latest update

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

[here is the image of error displayed when trying to launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ3zg.png)

After click on play it gives this error

here is the link of bug report

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hU_52V3u7t3p6-RyIVx35D90EhVz3X7i/view

Comment: Please provide some verbose logs, otherwise it's impossible to make a diagnosis.
Here's how you can do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336585/android-emulator-crash-logs

Comment: here is the link of document log

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hU_52V3u7t3p6-RyIVx35D90EhVz3X7i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please make the document available for anyone that has got the link

Comment: @AlessandroMuzzi
oh sorry! here is updated link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hU_52V3u7t3p6-RyIVx35D90EhVz3X7i/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949403/avd-with-android-studio-4-1-1-crashing-on-mac-os-high-sierra-with-error-qemu-sy and has still no answers.